# I cannot access GCE with my trial account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have problems on my Google Cloud trial account with accessing project's GCE/GKE.
All APIs related to GCE/GKE are enabled but I still get an error "Access Not Configured. Please activate the Compute API for your project"
when I try to use GCE and GKE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get into the Developers Console at all ? or is it that just the Compute Engine part is missing for you ? If you provide the Project ID/name I will be able to help you out further.

I can see this case is being worked on in [gce-discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/NTFqgkEckhw/keIqvojv-UcJ) group as well.